# OpenSSL application ignores default engine specified in openssl.cnf

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine

I'm trying to configure OpenSSL so that all OpenSSL applications on my device use a custom engine. I have the following in my openssl.cnf file:

```
config_diagnostics = 1
openssl_conf = openssl_def

[ openssl_def ]
engines = engine_section

[ engine_section ]
symcrypt = symcrypt_section

[ symcrypt_section ]
engine_id = symcrypt
dynamic_path = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1/libsymcryptengine.so
default_algorithms = ALL
init = 1
```

This works with the OpenSSL application (e.g. when running `openssl s_client -tls1_3 -connect google.com:443`) and with Nginx. However, it doesn't work with some other applications. For example, I copied the code [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) which uses the EVP APIs to do a simple symmetric encryption and decryption using AES-CBC. My engine supports AES-CBC, so this should work. But when I build this application (using `gcc -o main main.c -lcrypto -lssl`) and run it, my engine is not invoked or even loaded. Why not? Is there any way to force all callers of OpenSSL to use my engine **without modifying OpenSSL's code**? (Or at least all callers that dynamically link OpenSSL and don't explicitly specify their own engine?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that page says "Note that this uses the auto-init facility in 1.1.0 [and up]" and the default libcrypto init does not load the standard (or any) config; see [the man page for `OPENSSL_init_crypto`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/OPENSSL_init_crypto.html). Either you need to call explicitly with the LOAD_CONFIG flag, or call `OPENSSL_init_ssl`, or call (first) `SSL_CTX_new` which would usually be the first libssl routine used in a sensible program and implicitly does `OPENSSL_init_ssl`.

`openssl` commandline (in 1.1.0 up) does `OPENSSL_init_ssl`; I don't know about nginx, but if not it almost certainly starts with `SSL_CTX_new`.

In older versions (almost all) programs needed to (explicitly) call usually several initialization routines depending on what they were going to do, usually including [`OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms.html), and there was a build (compile-time) <s>kludge</s>option to have that routine automatically call [`OPENSSL_config`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/OPENSSL_config.html), which is pretty close to what you ask for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that man page previously but I guess I didn't fully grok this part: "This is not a default option for libcrypto. As of OpenSSL 1.1.1 this is a default option for libssl." So it seems that if you're using libssl, your application will automatically use openssl.cnf, but if you're only using libcrypto, it will not. That's a bummer, but good to know.